# Create chart in a new Tab using Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that creates a chart in a new tab. I have done this in javascript. How should this be converted into AngularJs.

```
function OpenWin() {

             var w = window.open();
             w.document.open();
             w.document.write('<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>');
             w.document.write('<select id="type" onchange="ChartFunc(this.value)"><option value="line">line</option><option value="column">column</option> <option value="area">area</option><option value="bar">bar</option></select>');
             var scriptHead = w.document.createElement("SCRIPT");
             var scriptHead1 = w.document.createElement("SCRIPT");
             var link = "http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js";
             var link1 = "http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js";




            scriptHead.onload = function() {

                  var script = w.document.createElement("SCRIPT");
                  w.document.body.appendChild(script);
                  var js = w.document.createTextNode('var a = localStorage.getItem("ImportOptions"); var jsona = JSON.parse(a); var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(jsona);function ChartFunc(value){ console.log(value); jsona.chart.type = value;var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(jsona); }');
                  script.appendChild(js);
                  w.document.close();
                  scriptHead1.src = link1;
                  w.document.head.appendChild(scriptHead1);

            }

            scriptHead.src = link;
            w.document.head.appendChild(scriptHead);

     }
```